# Why my unit test coverage is at the lower side?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, coverage.py

I have written a small class and function and unit test case for them.

from flask_restful import Resource

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, a, b ):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def add(self):
        return self.a + self.b

class CalcResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        cal = Calculator(2, 3)
        tr = cal.add()
        return tr
```

Below is the unit test for the above class

```
class TestCalcResource:
    def test_get(self):
        calc_res = CalcResource()
        res = calc_res.get()
        assert res == 5
```

On running the python coverage module on the test file. I am only getting 65% coverage. my aim is to touch 90%, that is the requirements. Please suggest.

[image]

I have added the screenshot.

Comment: You should exclude the **tests** code from the coverage report.

Comment: I didn't understand, please explain

Comment: Test coverage is calculated over the code you are testing, not the code you are testing with (the test cases).

Comment: You can generate  report to tell you what files were tested https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reporting.html - You may need to 'exclude' certain files from being part of that test.

Comment: You should absolutely include your tests in your coverage measurement: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202008/you_should_include_your_tests_in_coverage.html

We can't tell how you ran your tests, can you include the commands you used?

Comment: Also, BTW: "90%" isn't a good goal. What if the missing 10% is the critical tricky part of your code? Use coverage to point you to untested code, and then think about writing tests for that code.